# Get a value from a json answer

Tags: json

Here is a json return from a tomcat server:

```
{"id":"53344776e4b0cd5430be4e2e","deleted":false,"createdAt":1395935094790,"lastUpdate":1395935094790}
```

I need to identify the "id" object only, ie 53344776e4b0cd5430be4e2e

What is the best, faster an easier (haha) way to do that ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

If you hold this json in an object `obj`, you can simply do `obj.id`.